# How to resolve this warning?

Tags: julia

I tried to install "JuliaInXL" package in JuliaPro. It's popping up with the warning.

[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO6Ln.png)

Comment: Please post the error message as text not as an image so this question matches the StackOverflow rules.

Answer (score 0):

Usually upgrading packages and rebuilding your package helps.
So you could try:

```
using Pkg
pkg"update"
pkg"build JuliaInXL"
pkg"precompile"
```